# dijkstra algorithm in PHP issue

Tags: php, algorithm, dijkstra

I need some help, with a dijkstra algorithm in PHP.

The idea is develop a shortest path way inside a building. Entrance by a main entrance to a Hall and then 2 buildings, left (VB) and right (PS).

All names are VB-0-LIFT (building-floor-place).

https://github.com/phpmasterdotcom/DataStructuresForPHPDevs/blob/master/Graphs/graph-dijkstra.php

```
Array
(
    [ENTRANCE] => Array
    (
        [VB-0-HALL-CROSS] => 1
        [PS-0-HALL-CROSS] => 1
    )
    [VB-0-HALL-CROSS] => Array
    (
        [ENTRANCE] => 1
    )
    [PS-0-HALL-CROSS] => Array
    (
        [ENTRANCE] => 1
    )
)
```

My headache begins when I start try the routes:

A ) **OK**.     `$r->route('VB-0-HALL-CROSS', 'PS-0-HALL-CROSS')`

1. VB-0-HALL-CROSS
2. ENTRANCE
3. PS-0-HALL-CROSS

---

B) **FAIL**. `$r->route('PS-0-HALL-CROSS', 'VB-0-HALL-CROSS')`

1. Error: There's no route from PS-0-HALL-CROSS to VB-0-HALL-CROSS

---

C)  **OK**. `$r->route('ENTRANCE', 'PS-0-HALL-CROSS')`

1. ENTRANCE
2. PS-0-HALL-CROSS

---

I don't know if I don't understand dijkstra but when I connect VB-0-HALL-CROSS and PS-0-HALL-CROSS with lift combinations, such as
VB-0-HALL-CROSS -> VB lift 0 floor

- VB floor 0 -> VB floor 1, VB floor 2...
- VB floor 1 -> VB floor 0, VB floor 2...
- VB floor 2 -> VB floor 0, VB floor 1...

And this with 12 floors.

In case of floors, only works with some, others doesn't work.

Is there any problem with final vertex in dijkstra algorithm? Or any idea of why does it goes wrong?

```
while (!isEnded()) echo "thank you Colleagues";
```

(I can attach the code in github fully commented).

Comment: Is this a homework problem for school?

Comment: It's a personal script for helping people know path inside city hospital in my town.